# Flex wrap - positioning elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following design request:

[target design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT4yl.png)

And this is where I've gotten so far:

[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOUnd.png)

How can I control the element's positioning when using flex-wrap?
Notice that the last row's elements should be positioned like the ones above.

This is my code:

```css
.codes-card {
  width: 374px;
  height: 198px;
  padding: 24px 80px;
}

.codes-card-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 174px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="card codes-card">
  <div class="codes-card-inner">
    <span *ngFor="let authCode of authCodes" class="text-blue-300 regular-txt subtitle mb-2">teste</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you rather should not be using flexbox here to begin with, but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: or a `table` would seem more apprpriate

Answer (score 0):

Change you flex-direction to row and remove the justify and align content.  If you only want 2 per line, then give the spans a width of 50%.  This also allows a dynamic height for your container

```css
.codes-card {
  width: 374px;
  padding: 24px 80px;
}

.codes-card-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 174px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.codes-card-inner>span {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card codes-card">
  <div class="codes-card-inner">
    <span class="text-blue-300 regular-txt subtitle mb-2">teste</span>
    <span class="text-blue-300 regular-txt subtitle mb-2">teste</span>
    <span class="text-blue-300 regular-txt subtitle mb-2">teste</span>
    <span class="text-blue-300 regular-txt subtitle mb-2">teste</span>
    <span class="text-blue-300 regular-txt subtitle mb-2">teste</span>
    <span class="text-blue-300 regular-txt subtitle mb-2">teste</span>
    <span class="text-blue-300 regular-txt subtitle mb-2">teste</span>
    <span class="text-blue-300 regular-txt subtitle mb-2">teste</span>
    <span class="text-blue-300 regular-txt subtitle mb-2">teste</span>
    <span class="text-blue-300 regular-txt subtitle mb-2">teste</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using flex-wrap with no-wrap value, it will force elements to stay on one line,
and with the wrap value, it will put elements on multiple line, if they are too big to stay on one line.

But in your code, you just got one 'teste' card in the container...